# Как передать размер массива в функцию?

Tags: c

Нужно передать в функцию массив и внутри функции определить размер массива. Я пробую сделать так:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void pass(int buf[256]) {
    printf("size is %d\n", sizeof(buf));
}

void main() {
    int buf[256];

    pass(buf);
}
```

и получаю при печати

> size is 4

Как передать размер массива правильно и почему так, как я делаю, он не передается?

Comment: При таком написании "узнавать" размер буфера не нужно, он у вас уже задан - это число 256.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

А как вы себе представляете это работает? Функция на самом деле на вход получает адрес массива чисел.. один адрес и больше ничего. Для того чтобы передать размер массива вы должны его.. передать в буквальном смысле. Например, так

```
void pass(int * buff, int buffer_size) {
    printf("size is %d\n", buffer_size);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

В C++ можно сделать вот так:

```
template<size_t size>
void pass(int (&buf)[size])
{
    printf("size is %d\n", size);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
double mean(int n, double *a)
```

где n количество элементов массива

Answer (score -4):

а может правильнее применить sizeof без скобок, типа вот так:

```
void pass (int buf[])
{
   printf("size of buffer is %d\n", sizeof buf);
}
```

Comment: Может и правильнее, но только не на C!